# Compiling Nemo from source and installing it

Tags: linux-mint, deb

There is a fix for a bug in the Nemo repository, which I want to apply to my system (Linux Mint).

As the [developer guide](https://linuxmint-developer-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html) explains, I have cloned and `mint-build`' [mint-common](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintcommon), [xapps](https://github.com/linuxmint/xapp), and [nemo](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo).

First question, are these the required dependencies for Nemo?

Second question: The following `*.deb`s were created: (amongst other files)

```
mint-common_2.3.0_all.deb

xapps-doc_2.6.1_all.deb
xapps-common_2.6.1_all.deb
libxapp-dev_2.6.1_amd64.deb
libxapp-dbg_2.6.1_amd64.deb
libxapp1_2.6.1_amd64.deb
gir1.2-xapp-1.0_2.6.1_amd64.deb

nemo_5.8.4_amd64.deb
nemo-dbg_5.8.4_amd64.deb
nemo-data_5.8.4_all.deb
libnemo-extension-dev_5.8.4_amd64.deb
libnemo-extension1_5.8.4_amd64.deb
gir1.2-nemo-3.0_5.8.4_amd64.deb
```

Which of these would I install? All of them?

Third question: Anyone knows the meaning of the `gir1.2` in two of these files?

Comment: I've read building.html. Where have you got info also `xapps` repo is needed to build `Nemo`? TIA P.S. I've just built-installed Nemo installing newer xapps from Ubuntu mantic and doing manual work to satisfy dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is, [these are the requirements](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/b94dbd75e7e4b5403da26cfdb0948cbf494417a1/.github/workflows/build.yml#L24), but they are already installed when Nemo is installed, so it should not be necessary to compile and install them.

mtwebster was so friendly to [answer](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/3271#issuecomment-1644590609) the second question: Install all `*.deb`s created by [building](https://linuxmint-developer-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html) Nemo, by doing `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. Speak, install these:

```
gir1.2-nemo-3.0_5.8.4_amd64.deb
libnemo-extension1_5.8.4_amd64.deb
libnemo-extension-dev_5.8.4_amd64.deb
nemo-data_5.8.4_all.deb
nemo-dbg_5.8.4_amd64.deb
nemo_5.8.4_amd64.deb
```

He also [answered](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/3271#issuecomment-1645576468) the third question. Quote: (links by me)

> The [gir](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gi/unstable/GIRepository.html)1.2 package contains 'introspection' information for the extension library (libnemo-extension) which allows other languages, such as python, to utilize this C library to build extensions - we have some extensions that are written in C, others in python.
>
> Most libraries based on a common framework ([GLib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/)/[GObject](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/)) provide these packages. It's this capability that lets us write most of our Mint applications in python instead of C (which reduces development time, where performance isn't critical).